# Minio Slow performance when there are many users?

Tags: object, storage, minio, ceph

I have 1 minio object storage cluster, everyday it is running so ok but someday when there are many users using to put and download data that make performance too slow and maybe corrupt and especially with small data size. So how the way can i make performance better? pls help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is your traffic pattern?

You can try SeaweedFS S3, which should scale linearly by adding more file servers. And it excels at lots of small files.